# Subdividing part of spherical object without getting weird bumps

Tags: modeling

Ok so I use cube with level 4 subsurf modifier and 'to sphere' in edit mode so it becomes sphere, now I want to create some circles engraved into it so I need to create more topology there but when I subdivide few faces or subdivide smooth it creates weird bumps which are more notable under subsurf modifier. What would be good approach to do that. Here is what am I going for but I'm far away right now, I mean on these little circles on on three prong thingy, any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a couple of levels of subdivision below those already applied, a fairly conventional method to insert features like this into curved surfaces is to use a topology something like this:

[image]

Retain an intact,featureless, more subdivided copy of the sphere in the same place, and assign a Shrinkwrap modifier to your model with the intact sphere as target. (You can hide the target sphere, or put it on another layer)

Make a vertex group in your model, of all the vertices you want to conform to the target surface, (for example, excluding the ones shaded blue in the picture) and aim the Shrinkwrap at that group.

The result:

[image]

Matcap - showing Srinkwrap off:

[image]

Matcap - showing Srinkwrap on:

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks man this looks promising! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have one more question when I apply subsurf (4) on cube and round it using cast or to sphere it is fine it has some bumps but I want model to be relatively low-poly so I add level 2 subsurf to make it look better on render it creates artifacts on place where where corners of cube were, that s unless I use cast modifier. Would model like that be ok for selling online?

Comment: Is it OK when you Apply the Cast modifier? That would be fine.. but if it has to be subdivided _before_ casting, I don't think you can advertise it as lo-poly. Having said that, I've never sold on the open market.. only privately where that sort of thing can be discussed.  depending on your features, there are other typologies which _may_ be smoother with fewer polys.. e.g. a once Cat-Clark subdivided (all quad) icosphere .. which can be hard to work with.. your ref. is a cube, though...

Comment: When I first subsurfed cube than I used cast than I put subsurf again and I had to add cast/shrinkwrap to get rid of artifacts. Well icosphere would be hard to work with especially when uv-unwraping. So in your opinion what would be OK poly-count for this model?

Comment: Your ref looks like 20-40K? I really don't know, unless I know who/what it's for .. sorry not to be of more help...

Comment: ref is 240k but I think it's not displayed correctly on image. Let's say it will be used in game what about then? (I'm not going to do so I just trying to figure out whereabouts I know for games it should be relatively low-poly but I need some reference number) Well you were of help much, thank you!

Comment: Not my area, you'll have to ask around, but I think for games even now, it has to be a _lot_ lower than that for the final.. although tje hi-poly could be the basis for textures, normals etc...